# Why is the optimium shape in this problem not a square cross section?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

This math problem popped up in my textbook:

> A strip of metal is 24cm wide. This strip of metal is to be used to
>   form a length of  guttering for a house. The guttering will be open at
>   the top so water can flow through. What are the dimensions of the
>   cross section of the guttering if it is to hold the maximum volume of
>   water?

I solved it, and got the correct answer of Width = 12cm, Depth = 6cm (therefore you will have to fold up 6cm of metal on each side).

However, what I cant understand is why a square wouldn't give maximum volume. It is often considered to be a given that to maximise area, a rectangle of equal length sides (i.e. A square) should be used. However, why is it that in this problem a rectangle is the optimum shape?

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively, it is because you don't need material to cover the top of the gutter, so width costs half as much as height.  This should cause the solution to be wider than a square.  A clever approach is to note that if you make a copy of the gutter, invert it, and put it on top of your gutter, you have the classic problem of maximizing the area of a rectangle for a given perimeter.  As you say, this is solved by a square, so the gutter problem should be twice as wide as it is high.  All this is a bit of handwaving, and mvw's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Just considering rectangular cross sections, then 
$$
A(w) = w \frac{24 - w}{2} \quad (w \in [0, 24])
$$
At the borders of the interval we get $A=0$.

For local extrema we need
$$
0 = A'(w) = 12 - w
$$
so at $w = 12$ is a critical point.

As $A''(w) = -1 < 0$ it is a local maximum.

Indeed $A(12) = 72 > A(8) = 64$, so the square solution is not optimal.

If we had considered closed profiles we had the objective function:
$$
A(w) = w \frac{24 - 2 w}{2} \quad (w \in [0, 12])
$$
Note: That the domain changed as well.

Then again 
$$
0 = A'(w) = 12 - 2 w = 2(6 - w)
$$
so at $w = 6$ is a critical point. And this now is the square profile.

Conclusion: The open upper side makes the difference.

[image: gutter problems]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIB2q.png))

The open gutter objective function (green) and the closed gutter objective function (blue).
The red dots show the square cross section solution each.

Comment: Looks like this is answering the textbook problem.  But I thought the OP said ey already solved the textbook problem?

Comment: I tried to explain that the square is optimal if all four sides are involved, but here one side is not and a non-square rectangle is optimal.