# Optimization of rectangle. Find size of fence

Tags: optimization

I've got this, and im unsure how to proceed.
I need to build a fence. There is a building next to the fence, which is why i only need $3$ sides of the fence and it shall be a rectangle.
So this applies:
$o=2x+y$
The area shall be $558m^2$
So $558=l*w$
How can i find the smallest size of the fences sides?

I've tried the following:
558=x*y
y=558-x
Then put it in this:
o = 2x+y
So:
2x+(558-x) -> -x^2+558x
Then differentiated it to:
554-4x
Set it to 0 and found x to be 139.5

unfortunately that is not correct

Comment: Please consider including your thoughts. There are multiple ways to solve this problem. Have you learned about derivatives yet?

Comment: Edited my post now

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534655/why-is-the-optimium-shape-in-this-problem-not-a-square-cross-section/1534695#1534695)

Comment: I Can't see how it relates. He got the width. I've got the area on 558m2.

Comment: This is probably the oldest exercise in the history of Calculus textbooks, and it is certain that (something equivalent to) it has been asked and answered here many, many times. I encourage you to search the site for previous appearances.

Comment: I tried. I've found alot of similarities, and they didn't work in my case

Comment: Show us one of the similarities, and tell us why it doesn't work, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

This a standard maxima/minima problem. Shall be brief. Let Length and Width be $(x,y)$ respectively.
$$ \sigma= 2 x +y ,\quad A= xy, \quad y= \frac{A}{x}... \sigma= 2x+\frac{A}{x}$$
Differentiate, equate to zero, solve for $(x_{opt},\quad y_{opt} ) $ and finally find $\sigma_{min}$
$$\frac{d\sigma}{dx}=2-\frac{A}{x^2}=0 \rightarrow (x_{opt}=\sqrt{A/2}, y_{opt}=\sqrt{2 A}) $$

$$\rightarrow \sigma_{min}=2\sqrt{A/2}+\sqrt{2 A}=2\sqrt{2} A= 2\sqrt{ 2} * 558.0 \approx 1578.262 $$

Note that

$$ {x_{opt}} =\sqrt{558/2}= 16.708,{y_{opt}}=\sqrt{558*2} =33.4066 ;$$
$$ \frac{x_{opt}}{y_{opt}}= \dfrac{\sqrt{A/2}} {\sqrt{2 A}} =\dfrac12  $$

In your work it should be $y=558/x, $ but not $ y=558- x.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ and $w$ represent the length and width of the rectangle.  We are told that $l=358w^{-1}$.  We want to find values that minimize $2w+l$.  So
$$f(w)=2w+558w^{-1}$$ Differentiating and setting the derivative equal to zero gives us
$$f'(w)=2-558w^{-2}=0\\2=558w^{-2}\\2w^2=558\\w=\pm\sqrt{279}=\pm3\sqrt{31}$$